# Stuck within Induction

Tags: analysis, induction

I am taking a course in Analysis and have to prove that
$$
\sum_{j=0}^n j^3 = \frac{n^4}{4} + \frac{n^3}{2} + \frac{n^2}{4}
$$

I think until I had $n^4/4 + n^3/2 + n^2/4 + (n + 1)^3$ I did not make a mistake.

From there I seem to always make the same mistake and end up with
$$
\frac{n^4 + 6n^3 + 13n^2 + 12n + 4}{4}
$$

Any suggestions, hints, solutions?

Comment: Can you write down what the final formula is that you want/need to arrive at? It would be the formula you have in your first line, but with (n+1) substituted in for each n, and then expanded to individual terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier if you notice that
$$
\frac{n^4}{4}+\frac{n^3}{2}+\frac{n^2}{4}+(n+1)^3=\frac{n^2}{4}(n^2+2n+1)+(n+1)^3
$$
and that $n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$. Collect and find
$$
\frac{1}{4}(n+1)^2(n^2+4n+4)
$$
Can you finish now?

> $$\frac{1}{4}(n+1)^2(n+2)^2=\frac{1}{4}\bigl((n+1)^2((n+1)+1)^2\bigr)=\frac{1}{4}\bigl((n+1)^4+2(n+1)^3+(n+1)^2\bigr)$$

Comment: But it says n³ and not n² on the left site of your first equation?

Comment: @Luise Oh, sorry! A typo!

Comment: I arrived now at n²/4 (n+1)² + (n+1)³

Comment: I tried to approach it from the final equation backwards

Comment: And from backwards I arrived at your last formula from above but cannot bring them together

Comment: @Luise Added the spoiler; but try harder before looking at it.

Comment: Alright. Could you explain the very last step? I do not get this transformation

Comment: @Luise You want to get $\frac{(n+1)^4}{4}+\frac{(n+1)^3}{2}+\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}$, so express everything in terms of $n+1$, for instance $n+2=(n+1)+1$.

Comment: No, I meant how you came to (n + 1)⁴ from (n + 1)² + (n + 1)³. So basically from the one above the spoiler to the very last one of the spoiler.

Comment: @Luise $(n+1)^2((n+1)+1)^2=(n+1)^2((n+1)^2+2(n+1)+1)$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: for $f(n) = \frac{n^4}{4}+\frac{n^3}{2}+\frac{n^2}{4}$, evaluate what $f(n+1)$ is